# Relative child 100% width of relative parent

Tags: html, css

How can I have a relative div to be 100% of the width of its parent who is also relative?

I want to have a section on my webpage where I can show code snippets with the code tag however I want to be able to position the code so that it's width is 100% of it's parent container (regardless of the text inside).

```
function exactly_like_how_stackoverflow_handles_snippets() {
    return "In the same way that most websites handle code snippets";
}
```

I have tried to inspect how other sites have done it and I just can't decipher the css... maybe I am missing something

Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/84ejfou7/

Absolute positioning would be perfect if it wasn't for the fact that I want the code snippet to be positioned in between text (again, exactly like the code snippet above)

I have tried literally everything I can think of, and the only thing that works is directly specifying the width in pixels however this is **not a solution** as my site is responsive and the width of the parent is a percentage.

Comment: You mean like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pdybgpod/?

Comment: yep! display: block -- thanks dude

Comment: I'm so confused that I typed confused 'foncused'

Comment: lol wut?? You mean my question wasn't clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the display property of your code tag to block:

```
.parent code {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  display: block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pdybgpod/)**